# Check that emails are valid in Google Apps Scripts

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a Google Sheet that has a column of over 50 emails. I need to be able to send an email to each one separately, but determine which ones are invalid emails.
My code:

```
var failureCount = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < recipients.length; i++) {
  try {
    MailApp.sendEmail(recipients[i], subject, body, { htmlBody: htmlBody, noReply: true});
  } catch (err) {
    failureCount++;
  }
}
```

I have tested this and it seems that an error is only thrown when recipients[i] has a value that is not in the correct email format. It won't throw an error if the email address does not exist. I need to be able to determine if the email address exists or not and count it as one of the failures if it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Apps Script does not have a method to check if an email is valid or not. However, you can try [Email Checkers tools online](https://email-checker.net/check).